# Is Spearman's cor.test in R tie corrected or not?

Tags: r, correlation

I was wondering if the cor.test function in R to compute Spearman's rho is **tie-corrected** or not.
I couldn't find a straight answer in the [official R documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/cor.test.html).

An example of tie corrected Spearman is found in:

> Cureton, Edward E. The average spearman rank criterion correlation
>   when ties are present. Psychometrika 23, no. 3 (September 1958):
>   271-272.

Thanks for any hint,
Mulone

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "official" documentation is the code itself. And looking there, one sees that there is provision for correction for ties through the use of `pkendall()`.

```
stats:::cor.test.default
```

You will also get background information at [this recent posting on SO regarding the Spearman-rho and three Kendall-tau's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711395/spearman-correlation-and-ties-in-r)

Comment: wow, I actually didn't know it was so easy to see the source code in R.

Comment: Hold on, actually Kendall handles ties (which is expected), but Spearman seems simply to do: r <- cor(rank(x), rank(y)). I can't see any sign of TIES-related logic in the Spearman section of that function.

Comment: I was assuming the question was asking whether cor.test() could return a tie corrected rank-based statistic. One would do so by choosing `method="kendall"`.

Comment: Ok, so the answer to my question is no :-(

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the unhappiness. The Kendall-tau has a better behavior with smaller samples, and is not as subject to spurious effects from small numbers of large discrepant rankings.

Comment: The unhappiness comes from the fact that I need a tie-corrected Spearman to compare certain results with other people who haven't used Kendall. A lot of people don't like Kendall because it's generally lower than Spearman, and they don't report it. Any implementation of a tie-corrected Spearman anyway?

Comment: Peter Dalgaard seems to think the cor.test spearman _is_ tie-corrected. Why not pose a test case? http://markmail.org/search/?q=list%3Aorg.r-project.r-help+tie-corrected+spearman#query:list%3Aorg.r-project.r-help%20tie-corrected%20spearman+page:1+mid:h4vih4jlkszokxxl+state:results . Prof Ripley also thinks the code should be consulted: http://markmail.org/search/?q=list%3Aorg.r-project.r-help+ties+correction+spearman#query:list%3Aorg.r-project.r-help%20ties%20correction%20spearman+page:1+mid:nwamobsmjjj2lz7w+state:results

Comment: This response is marked as the accepted answer, but it doesn't actually answer the question. The question is "Is Spearman's cor.test in R tie corrected or not?" and the supplied answer is "Use Kendall's tau."

Comment: @rev_bird No. The supplied answer says the code passes the calculations off to `pkendall`. "Luke, Use the code!"