# Calculate Spearman correlation and corrected p-value (with ties)

Tags: r

I am calculating spearman correlation between x and y variables (both datasets have some values that are equal), using R. I used:

```
cor.test(x, y, method= "spearman")
```

And I get a warning message:

```
Cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

My x data it's like: 0.84, 0.84, 0.07, 0.173
My y data it's like: 6, 2, 4, 2

I would like to solve this problem. I read these two questions:

- [Spearman correlation and ties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711395/spearman-correlation-and-ties)
- [Is Spearman's cor.test in R tie corrected or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723930/is-spearmans-cor-test-in-r-tie-corrected-or-not?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But I still cannot solve my problem. Can you help me? I understand that maybe I could use kendall instead of spearman although, using the same function (changing "spearman" to "Kendall") I get the same warning message. I also saw an ans
I would like to calculate spearman correctly is this possible or not even with ties?
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: For questions like this StackOverflow requires a complete, minimal, reproducible example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Notice the word "exact". It still give you an R value and a p-value and they are approximately correct.

Comment: I edit my question..can you help me?