# Change colors in ggpairs now that params is deprecated

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, ggally

I saw these posts 
[GGally::ggpairs plot without gridlines when plotting correlation coefficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21810675/ggallyggpairs-plot-without-gridlines-when-plotting-correlation-coefficient)
[use ggpairs to create this plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21716567/use-ggpairs-to-create-this-plot)

After reading I was able to implement this hack https://github.com/tonytonov/ggally/blob/master/R/gg-plots.r and my plot looks like this

[image: my plot]

I think this is a good result but I cannot change the colors.

A MWE is this

```
library(ggally)

# load the hack
source("ggally_mod.R") 
# I saved https://github.com/tonytonov/ggally/blob/master/R/gg-plots.r as "ggally_mod.R"
assignInNamespace("ggally_cor", ggally_cor, "GGally")

ggpairs(swiss)
```

Now I want to run

```
ggpairs(swiss, 
 lower=list(continuous="smooth", wrap=c(colour="blue")),
 diag=list(continuous="bar", wrap=c(colour="blue")))
```

But the colours remain the same. Is there a way to change the colours now that params is not working anymore?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are not using `wrap` correctly - 
  [see the vignette for details](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GGally/vignettes/ggpairs.html). Also for the diagonal you now have to use the function `barDiag` (but `ggpairs` gives very helpful errors to tell this)

So for your example, we can change the `colour` of the points in the lower 
panels and the `fill` of the bars below

```
library(GGally)
library(ggplot2)
ggpairs(swiss[1:3], 
        lower=list(continuous=wrap("smooth", colour="blue")),
        diag=list(continuous=wrap("barDiag", fill="blue")))
```

However, as the colour of the smooth is hard coded (see `ggally_smooth`), to change its
colour you need to define you own function to pass. So [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35085261/how-to-use-loess-method-in-ggallyggpairs-using-wrap-function/35088740#35088740)

```
my_fn <- function(data, mapping, pts=list(), smt=list(), ...){
              ggplot(data = data, mapping = mapping, ...) + 
                         do.call(geom_point, pts) +
                         do.call(geom_smooth, smt) 
                 }

# Plot 
ggpairs(swiss[1:4], 
        lower = list(continuous = 
                       wrap(my_fn,
                            pts=list(size=2, colour="red"), 
                            smt=list(method="lm", se=F, size=5, colour="blue"))),
                     diag=list(continuous=wrap("barDiag", fill="blue")))
```

---

In a similar way, here is a way to define a new upper correlation function (similar to what you have)

```
cor_fun <- function(data, mapping, method="pearson", ndp=2, sz=5, stars=TRUE, ...){

    x <- eval_data_col(data, mapping$x)
    y <- eval_data_col(data, mapping$y)

    corr <- cor.test(x, y, method=method)
    est <- corr$estimate
    lb.size <- sz* abs(est) 

    if(stars){
      stars <- c("***", "**", "*", "")[findInterval(corr$p.value, c(0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 1))]
      lbl <- paste0(round(est, ndp), stars)
    }else{
      lbl <- round(est, ndp)
    }

    ggplot(data=data, mapping=mapping) + 
      annotate("text", x=mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), y=mean(y, na.rm=TRUE), label=lbl, size=lb.size,...)+
      theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
  }


ggpairs(swiss, 
        lower=list(continuous=wrap("smooth", colour="blue")),
        diag=list(continuous=wrap("barDiag", fill="blue")),
        upper=list(continuous=cor_fun))
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this is very clear and provides an efficient solution

Comment: I use this ```cor_fun``` but instead using the ```method='spearman'```. I get warnings says: ```Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (stat_density2d).
In cor.test.default(x, y, method = method) :
  Cannot compute exact p-value with ties```. Could you please give a hint?

Comment: re the correlation warning https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711395/spearman-correlation-and-ties. I'm not sure re the stat_density2d error -- are you using a different geom to the above answer? -- would probably need to see code / data

Comment: when using spearman method, this warning is nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 4):

You can modify some parameters of GGally functions by using `wrap()` [as explained here](http://ggobi.github.io/ggally/index.html#function_wrapping). But not all parameters are named for `wrap` to be useful. For example, if you try to change default palette with a manual colour scale within `wrap` you may get an error like `Error in wrap("cor",…) all parameters must be named arguments`. In that case you may build [custom functions](http://ggobi.github.io/ggally/index.html#custom_functions) to generate any sort of ggplot object appropriate for the upper, lower or diagonal sections of the matrix plot.

However, there is a (safer) shortcut if you want to change some parameters (not named in GGally functions to be `wrap`ped) without creating a custom function to design a ggplot object. You just call an already existing GGally function within a function call, adding the extra ggplot parameters. For example, to provide a manual scale colour for three categories (in the new column swiss$groups):

```
swiss$groups <- gl(n = 3, k = 1, length = nrow(swiss), labels = c("A", "B", "C"))

ggpairs(swiss, mapping = aes(colour = groups), columns = 1:6,
    upper = list(continuous = function(data, mapping, ...) {
         ggally_cor(data = data, mapping = mapping, size = 2) + scale_colour_manual(values = c("black", "dark green", "red"))}),
    lower = list(continuous = function(data, mapping, ...) {
         ggally_smooth(data = data, mapping = mapping, alpha = .2) + scale_colour_manual(values = c("black", "dark green", "red"))}),
    diag = list(continuous = function(data, mapping, ...) {
         ggally_barDiag(data = data, mapping = mapping, alpha = .5) + scale_fill_manual(values = c("black", "dark green", "red"))}))
```

Comment: Ths is also useful if you want to apply different `theme` elements to each section (`upper`, `lower`, or `diag`). For example, keeping grids by default in `lower` and `diag` but removing them in `upper`

Comment: Excellent! I was wondering if you know how to change the gray color of the standard error of the smooth lines. Thanks.