# Coloring points based on variable with R ggpairs

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

I'm trying to reproduce the figure in https://tgmstat.wordpress.com/2013/11/13/plot-matrix-with-the-r-package-ggally/ with the code

```
require(GGally)
data(tips, package="reshape")
ggpairs(data=tips, title="tips data", colour = "sex")
```

However, in the plot I get the points are not colored based on sex, instead they are all the same color.  I get the following warning

> Warning message:
>   In warn_if_args_exist(list(...)) :
>    Extra arguments: 'colour' are being ignored.  If these are meant to be >aesthetics, submit them using the 'mapping' variable within ggpairs with >ggplot2::aes or ggplot2::aes_string.

I've tried adding ggplot2::aes(colour = sex), but that did not work either.

Does anyone else here have the same problem?  I'm using R version 3.3.1 and GGally_1.2.0.

Thanks.

Comment: what does "did not work" mean?

Comment: @BenBolker I meant that it did not color the points based on the category.  I see your solution below and it worked for me!  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`GGally` has been under fairly rapid development, so it's not surprising that a blog post from 2013 has out-of-date code.  When I run your code with `GGally` 1.2.0 I get the same warning.  It works for me if I add the mapping:

```
require(GGally)
data(tips, package="reshape")
g1 <- ggpairs(data=tips, title="tips data",
  mapping=ggplot2::aes(colour = sex),
  lower=list(combo=wrap("facethist",binwidth=1)))
```

Following [the wiki page](https://ggobi.github.io/ggally/ggpairs.html) for the `wrap()` incantation to stop complaints about needing to set `binwidth` in `stat_bin` ...

[image]

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46964952/2052738) if you want to change those default colours with a manual scale (`wrap` won't accept `manual_colour_scale`).