# Round correlation with GGally pair plot

Tags: r, ggally

To increase the readability of a pair plot, with many variables, I would like to round the coefficient of correlation provided by `ggpairs()` function.

In the following example, instead of having a coefficient of 0.807 displayed, I would like to have 0.8.

```
library(GGally)

data(cars)

ggpairs(cars,
  upper = list(continuous = wrap(ggally_cor, alignPercent = 0.8, size = 10)))
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicated: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47496364/rounding-digits-in-ggpairs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `digits=2` in the `ggpairs()` call for 2 digit r coefficient.

The updated `ggpairs()` would be like that;

```
ggpairs(cars,
        upper = list(continuous = wrap(ggally_cor, alignPercent = 0.8, digits=2, size = 10)))
```

[image]

I hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling for ggally cor, call for text using a predefined correlation where you've already rounded. That way the text is the rounded coefficient.

more tweaking found here: [link](https://github.com/ggobi/ggally/issues/139)

```
ct <- cor.test(cars$speed,cars$dist)
r <- ct$estimate
rt <- format(r, digits=2)  #can have 1 instead of 2
 # just demonstrating that .807 becomes .81

ggpairs(cars,
        upper = list(continuous = function(data, mapping, ...) {
          ggally_text(label = as.character(rt), mapping = mapping)}), 
        lower = list(continuous = 'smooth'), 
        axisLabels = "internal"
)
```