# Error message: 'x' and 'y' must have the same length

Tags: r, correlation

I keep getting the following error message in R whilst trying to run a simple correlation. Can anyone help?

Error message is:

> Error in cor.test.default(my_data$Year, my_data$Total, method =
> "spearman") :    'x' and 'y' must have the same length

this is the code I am using:

```
library("dplyr")
library ("ggpubr")
library("devtools")

my_data<- read.csv(file.choose())
set.seed(1234)
dplyr::sample_n(my_data, 10)

ggdensity(my_data$Total, 
      main = "Density plot of barrier closures",
      xlab = "Year ending")

ggqqplot(my_data$Total)

shapiro.test(my_data$Total)


cor.test(my_data$Year, my_data$Total, method = "spearman")
```

The data I am using has two columns in a CSV file, one is labelled "year" one is labelled "total". Both columns have 39 numeric entries so the lengths of the columns is identical. Every other part of the code works fine. I am using the latest version of R and latest version of all the packages

Edit: Someone asked for my data frame so here it is:

```
structure(list(ï..Year = 83:121, Total = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 24L, 4L, 
20L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 50L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 9L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -39L
))
```

Comment: Hello, did you check the nature of *my_data*? Try for example to transform *my_data* into a matrix with `my_data <- as.matrix(my_data)` and still get the error message?

Comment: Please consider adding an example of your dataframe in your post. As it stands, it is clearly impossible to help you as the problem originates from your dataframe. You could edit your post by adding the output of `dput(my_data)`, so that people can reproduce your issue. thanks

Comment: It may just be a typo in your message, but you say one column is "year", yet you refer to "Year" in the code.  *Please* post a reproducible example.

Comment: You'll get that error if you misspecify one of the column names (but you get a different error if you misspecify both).

Comment: @BastienDucreux I've added my dataframe to the original post now.

Comment: @gdrouard when I transform to a matrix I get a different error message when I try to run a Spearmans: Error in my_data$Total : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Answer (score 1):

As user2554330 rightly stated: *You'll get that error if you misspecify one of the column names*. As can be seen from *the output of `dput(my_data)`*, the first column's name is not `Year`, but `ï..Year`. The given error does not occur with

```
cor.test(my_data$ï..Year, my_data$Total, method = "spearman")
```

(You may be able to remove the merging of this *byte order mark* with the column name by adding the argument `fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM"` in the `read.csv()` call.)

Comment: I now get this error message instead: Warning message:
In cor.test.default(my_data$ï..Year, my_data$Total, method = "spearman") :
  Cannot compute exact p-value with ties

Comment: @DanielGrove you may find clues to understand why you get the warning here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711395/spearman-correlation-and-ties